# Is it possible to install Android L on a device that will not get the update in the future?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia

I have Sony Xperia M2, and as you probably know, this phone **will not** get the new Android L update from Sony.
So is there any way to install the Android L manually?
I don't care to root my device and install a custom ROM which compatible with the new version... but is it actually possible to update my device version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why yes, you can. Mind you that lollipop is not a daily driver for your phone yet, it's in alpha stage. Now, I don't have the same phone as you but the process will be pretty much the same.

Firstly, you need to understand what you're going to be doing so read any noob guide on www.xda-developers.com (it's this site you're going to be sticking to and I'm sorry I'm writing this from my phone and couldn't find the noob guide I was looking for, I'll edit when I'm on PC).

This is your phone's forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-m2

Now follow this:

1.Unlock your bootloader:Find a guide in android development section

2.Root your phone:Find a guide in android development section.

3. Flash a custom recovery:Find a custom recovery in android development or original android development. By now, you probably already know how to flash.
4. Flash CM12:Find CM12 in original android development, follow instructions.

Congrats, you will now be experiencing lollipop.

WARNING: Read and follow every post carefully and thoroughly, any mistake can end up bricking your phone. Do this at your own risk, I shall not be responsible if your brick your phone. You have been warned.

Happy flashing.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to install a newer version of Android on that (and probably every other) device.

First you have to make sure the *bootloader* of your device is unlocked. In doubt just try to unlock it, it won't relock again without notifying you.
Then you flash (in most cases) a custom recovery like CWM, TWRP or Philz.
After that you can install every custom ROM or other zip on your phone.

> The best place for specific Android devices is [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com). (imo)
>   Most developers meet there and publish their custom ROMs like CyanogenMod as well as modded official firmwares.

For your device there is a big guide on how to unlock your bootloader right on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2743694
Installing a custom ROM is then done through your recovery.